# 404 error when testing method with RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, junit, resttemplate

I am trying to run unit tests for a method which downloads a file using a RestTemplate. I've followed multiples topics on the subjects, but contrary to them, when I run the test I get a 404 error.

Here's my method :

```
@Api(value = "Telecharger fichier sas")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(PUBLIC_BASE_URL)
public class TelechargerFichierRestController extends BaseController {

    /** Size of a byte buffer to read/write file */    
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    /**Header name */
    private static final String HEADER_NAME = "REMOTE_USER";


    /**
     * Telecharger fichier dans le répertoire download
     * 
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @ApiOperation(value = "Telecharger fichier dans le répertoire download")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sasDl/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadFichier(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        int bytesRead;
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

        // initialisation de headers
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String remoteUser = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);
        headers.add(HEADER_NAME, remoteUser);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

        // recupération de ressource depuis psas_m
        ResponseEntity<Resource> result = template.exchange(PSASConfig.PREFIX_URL_API_PSAS, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                Resource.class);
        // get output stream of the response
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

        try {
            inputStream = result.getBody().getInputStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        // write bytes read from the input stream into the output stream
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    }

}
```

And here's the test :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TelechargerFichierRestTest {


    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Mock
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;
    /**
     * RestController
     */
    @InjectMocks
    private TelechargerFichierRestController restController


    /**
     * Test method for {@link fr.cnamts.brrsm.services.app.majRequeteSAS.service.impl#DownloadFichier()}.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testDownloadFichier() throws Exception {
        Mockito.doReturn(new ResponseEntity<Resource>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED))
            .when(mockRestTemplate)
            .exchange(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<String>> any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>> any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Object>anyVararg());
        restController.downloadFichier(request, response);
        Mockito.verify(response).getOutputStream();
        Mockito.verify(request).getHeader("REMOTE_USER");

    }

}
```

Can someone tell me why the answer is 404, and how to avoid it? Thanks.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }` This makes no scence, because you only wrap the exception with an object of the same execption class. remove the ry catch block

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking 5-arg method of RestTemplate

```
Mockito.doReturn(new ResponseEntity<Resource>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)).when(mockRestTemplate)
.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class), ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<String>> any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>> any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Object>anyVararg());
```

but testing 4-arg method

```
template
.exchange(PSASConfig.PREFIX_URL_API_PSAS, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class);
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I tried this from another topic. But I tested with only 4 args in the doReturn().when() and it return the same 404 error.

Comment: Another issue in your code is that in test you mock an injected bean of RestTemplate class, but in real code you construct new instance of RestTemplate on each request. So try to autowire RestTemplate into your controller as a managed bean